# Can we use parameters in oozie decision node?

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

I am trying to execute a **decision control node** in oozie 3.3.2 but getting javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException

Encountered "{"

```
<decision name="decision-wf">
 <switch>
           <case to="another_wf">
                ${fs:fileSize(${OutputDir}/000000_0) gt 100 }
           </case>

           <default to="fail-wf"/>
</switch>
```

How should I pass the parameter in String format as the above mentioned FS method expects String input ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [document](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html) it appears,

You need to pass hardcoded i.e. enclosed in `'` like in `${fs:fileSize('/usr/foo/myinputdir'/1000) gt 10 }`

or

just the parameter name `${fs:fileSize(OutputDir/1000) gt 10 }`

This `OutputDir` might be specified in the `<config>` sections of the workflow OR the `.properties` file OR passed at time of submitting the job using `-D`

Comment: I am already doing this way.This forum post [link](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/Oozie-wf-decision-node-is-this-how-to-pass-the-parameters-into/td-p/2091) suggests that it should be valid though.

Comment: can we have arguments for threshold value as below ?  I tried this and its not working. ${fs:fileSize('/user/mytable') lt "${ThresholdSize}" }

Comment: @Satha I am not sure about this but can you try without the `$` sign?

Comment: Ok.I tried so and getting this : An exception occured trying to convert String "{ThresholdSize}" to type "java.lang.Long"

Comment: @satha Can you please try this way too ? `${fs:fileSize('/user/mytable') lt ThresholdSize` ?

Comment: It worked in this fashion. ${fs:fileSize('/user/mytable') lt ThresholdSize * GB }.  Thanks Suvarna for the help

Comment: I have a small clarification, in the following the proceed email case will happen only when the file size is always less than 10 GB right, I am getting a weird behaviour when the file size is greater than 10 GB also this proceed case is happening. any idea ? <decision name="SizeCheck">
         <switch>
            <case to="sendProceedEmail">
              ${fs:fileSize('/user/myDir') lt 10 * GB }
            </case>
            <default to="sendEmail" />
         </switch>
</decision>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In fact you can combine multiple parameters with the concat function (which, I think, would help with the original poster's question).

For example if ${location} and ${date} are two params defined in your config file:

```
<decision name="check-directory-exists">
     <switch>
        <case to="load-directory">
          <!-- check if the directory at this location for this date exists -->
          ${fs:exists(concat(location, date))}
        </case>
        <!-- The directory doesn't exist, there is nothing to do -->
        <default to="end" />
     </switch>
 </decision>
```

and if location and date need a '/' between them, you have to do this:

```
${fs:exists(concat(concat(location, "/"), date))}
```